# How to restore the format style after paste a formatted text?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

For example, I copy and paste some red text and keep typing. The newly typed text will remain red. Is it a quick way to restore the format style the same before pasting the red text? (And keep the format of pasted text unchanged (in red in this example))

Comment: Have you considered writing a macro and binding it to a key combo which can push and pop the current font and paragraph styles?

Comment: Ctrl+Space is the shortcut for "Clear all styles", so you could paste, press that combo and keep typing. Of course, that won't revert back to the *previous* style you were using...

Answer (score 4):

There are any number of ways in which you might do this.  Which one works best for you depends on your own preferred working style.  Here are a few of the easier ways:

- Reset it to the normal style by clicking the **Normal** button on the **Style** section of the Home tab of the ribbon.  You can quickly access this via the keyboard by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the correct style is highlighted (Normal is usually first).
- Click an area of the formatting you want to use, click the **Format Painter** button on the ribbon, then click the area you are typing in.  All formatting characteristics will be copied in from your original text before the paste.
- Probably the easiest way is to just add an extra space or return before pasting, then paste the new text between the spaces or paragraph marks.  By having a character (space or paragraph) of your normal text in the latter part of the text and then pasting before that, you keep everything below the paste the same way it was to begin with.

Comment: 1) doesn't work. The color is still red while other style may be reset. I usually use (2) and (3). But (2) is too cumbersome and it's easy to forget (3) when you think the style is the same but sometime there is minor different. It's actually an important feature and I don't know why Microsoft has never done it.

Comment: I use 3) all the time, but type a space and then a letter.  If you click to focus in front of this letter, and paste you can then click after the letter and maintain font formatting because the single letter acts like a placeholder for your formatting.  This way Format Painter is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Came here hoping to find a better answer than my own, but..

If I paste **xyz** into some text like "hello world **xyz**", I'll just

1. copy and paste a snippet of my original text to the end of **xyz** like "hello world **xyz**hello"
2. type something new like "hello world **xyz**hello something new"
3. remove pasted text to end up with "hello world **xyz** something new"